# Как открыть второй сайт через 3 сек, сгенерировав клик?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, click

Всем привет, есть небольшой скрипт на jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".main").on('click', 'button.okbtn', function () {
    window.open('http://site1.com/reg.php', '_blank');
    window.open('http://domen2.com/page.php', '_blank');
```

При клике по элементу открывается 2 сайта. Как сделать чтобы при клике по кнопке открывался 1-й домен, затем через 3 секунды генерировался клик и открывался 2-й домен.

И ещё, второй вопрос, подскажите отдельным примером как сделать, чтобы при клике по кнопке открывался 1-й домен, затем через 3 секунды в текущей странице (т.е. на странице в которой пользователь кликает на кнопку) генерироваля фрейм на на всю страницу, в котором загружался бы 2-й домен

Comment: Да вы, батенька, вредитель...

Answer (score 0):

Просто поставь таймер.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".main").on('click', 'button.okbtn', function () {
window.open('http://site1.com/reg.php', '_blank');

setTimeout(function(){
window.open('http://domen2.com/page.php', '_blank');
},3000)
```

Comment: Сработает, если в браузере стоит запрет всякого всплывающего, как обычно теперь бывает?